# How to integrate selfstarter to rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am learning rails (via railstutorial and treehouse) and want to create a basic crowdfunding site that allows users to fund their ideas. It seems like the selfstarter gem has quite a bit of work done already. How would I integrate the gem into my site? So far my site allows users to sign up.

Alternatively, if this is not advised or feasible, how would I create my own crowdhosting features w/payment?

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make a fork of the app with

```
git clone git clone https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter.git
```

Then cd into the directory selfstarter

```
cd selfstarter
```

Look at your current remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter.git (push)
```

and update them to be for you with:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your-github-username/selfstarter.git
```

Make your changes as usual, add and commit them and then push to what is now your own repository with

```
git push origin master
```

Another option is to leave `origin` as is and created new remotes for yourself for your own repo with `git remote add [name] [url]`.  This is similar to what I do with heroku when I need two remotes for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Selfstarter isn't a gem. It looks like it's intended to be a starting point for a project, not something to be integrated into other projects. If you want to use it you'll be better off starting fresh with Selfstarter (following the very comprehensive [instructions in the README](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter/blob/master/README.md)) and then taking any code you need from your existing project and integrating it into Selfstarter.